# convert from a dataset to list

Tags: string-manipulation, dataset, associations

I have a `Dataset` of only 1 column to start with, and I want to `StringJoin` every element there.  Got the error message

> StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in StringJoin[Dataset [<<33>>]].

Here is code to reproduce:

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = Dataset[ToString /@ a]
c = StringJoin[b]
```

Tried `Normal[StringJoin[b]] & Normal[b]`, neither worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `StringJoin[(# & /@ Normal@b)]` is this what you're looking for? 
Edit: Commented before seeing WReach's answer. It's a really nice way of doing this! :)

Comment: This solution works, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StringJoin` is not one of the functions that support a dataset argument.  We can, however, use `StringJoin` as a query operator:

```
b[StringJoin]

(* "123" *)
```

We can see the functions which do accept a dataset argument by inspecting the output of:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[Dataset]
```

[image: PrintDefinitions screenshot]

The list is quite a bit longer than will fit in a screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

In:

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = Dataset[ToString /@ a];

b[StringJoin, All] (*Method 1, apply StringJoin to the contents of all columns/a specific column*)
StringJoin @@ b (*Method 2, replace Dataset head with StringJoin*)
```

Out:

```
"123"
"123"
```